# How to get customized attributes value of a html radio button in php

Tags: php, html

```
<form id="test" method="post" action="getValue.php">
<input type="submit" name="sample" value="A" customizedValue1="1" customizedValue2="X"/>
<input type="submit" name="sample" value="B" customizedValue1="2" customizedValue2="Y"/>
</form>
```

I want to know how to get the value of customized attributes of between several radio buttons like example above by using php.

How can i get the value of customizedValue1  and customizedValue2 in php?

Thanks

Comment: If u want the values of those customized attributes in PHP then, use javascript to get those values & make an AJAX call to respective PHP file with all those data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access directly from PHP to this values, you need to pass them as AJAX `POST` values to the PHP file like this:

**FORM**

```
<form id="test" method="post" action="getValue.php">
<input type="radio" name="sample" value="A" customizedValue1="1" customizedValue2="X"/>
<input type="radio" name="sample" value="B" customizedValue1="2" customizedValue2="Y"/>
<button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#test').on('submit',function(){

   var customizedValue1 = $('#test input[name=sample]:checked').attr('customizedValue1');

   $.post('getValue.php',{'customizedValue1':customizedValue1});

});
```

On **getValue.php** you can access to the value:

```
echo $_REQUEST['customizedValue1'];
```

Comment: Hi Troyer, do I need to add some code in <form> tag to use the script? I tried this code in my file but it still does not work. By the way, the type of <input> is "radio", so how should i change the code you typed?

Comment: I added the HTML for the form, you should look what's AJAX and how it works, it's to broad to explain it there.

Answer (score 0):

If they are connected to eachother somehow. You can also use the values as an array in html form

```
<form id="test" method="post" action="getValue.php">
<input type="text" name="data[A][customizedValue1]" value="value1" />
<input type="text" name="data[A][customizedValue2]" value="value2" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $customizedValue1 = $_POST['data']['A']['customizedValue1'];
   $customizedValue2 = $_POST['data']['A']['customizedValue2'];
   echo $customizedValue1;
   echo $customizedValue2;
}
?>
```